# Checking if a Git Branch Exists in Batch

Tags: git, batch-file, jenkins, git-branch

I am trying to determine if a git branch exists in a specific location using batch through Jenkins. From what I understand, Jenkins runs the commands similar to how a Batch shell script would run. After researching this question on Stack Overflow already (and finding several pages about this similar question) I now have code to check if a git branch exists. Here is the code:

```
@echo off
cd D:\git\ceos

git rev-parse --verify temp
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0  (
    echo Branch Exists
) else (
    echo Branch Does Not Exist
)
```

Here is my problem: If the branch "temp" does exist, this code works perfectly and returns "Branch exists." However, if "temp" does not exist, the Jenkins job fails saying

```
fatal: Needed a single revision
Branch Does Not Exist
```

So clearly, it is still going into the correct branch of the if statement as it is returning "Branch Does Not Exist" but is still failing for some reason.

My question is this: even though the logic of my code works (thanks to other Stack Overflow questions), how do I keep this job from failing when there is no branch temp?

**Update:**
It turns out that the reason the job was failing is that the %ERRORLEVEL% was being set to something other than 0 and upon reaching the end of the script, the Jenkins job could not pass without having a proper exit code. Therefore, in the "else" branch, I just set the errorlevel back to 0, and it passed.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your immediate problem as stated above, but might not actually be what you want. Replace your current git command with:

```
git branch --list | findstr /snip temp
```

What you probably want to do is attempt a [git checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) and exit with an error if that fails:

```
git checkout temp
```

This will sync the local files to the content in temp if it exists. The error message returned by git should also be sufficient in this case and is more informative than yours:

```
error: pathspec 'temp' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```